# xslt value-of not being parsed

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to generate several text files, depending of number of object elements present in input XML document. For this purpose I am using `result-document()` (xslt 2.0) function, and transformations are evaluated by Saxon.

For some reason, when running the transformation in Saxon, I am not getting values from some `xsl:value-of` functions, but when I run standard XSLT debug (I need to comment out the `xsl:result-document` function) in VS 2010 Ultimate, I am getting expected result.The problem is rooted in **FillTheObjectFromForm** templates `xsl:for-each` loop.

Can someone please point out what is wrong in my template?

To keep this post short, I've uploaded XML and result files to http://hotfile.com. Here are code samples and input XML:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dbs:MetaDataRoot FreeForm="true" xmlns:dbs="http://stefan/DbStructure">  
  <orm:MappingRoot FreeForm="False" MapDataStructure="ASPBaza" TransactionType="ADONET" Namespace="GeneratedCode" xmlns:orm="http://stefan/ORM.xsd">
    <orm:Build MapDataStructure="ASPBaza" />
    <orm:Assembly Namespace="GeneratedCode" MapDataStructure="ASPBaza" Name="BusinessLayer"> 
      <orm:Objects>
        <orm:Object  OriginalName="Kupac" Name="Kupac" TableName="Kupac" CollectionName="Kupac" Caption="Kupac" >          
          <orm:Properties>
            <orm:Property Name="SifraKupca"  IsPrimaryKey="true" ControlType="System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" ControlPrefix="txt"  ControlName="txtSifraKupca" BindProperty="Text" Display="false"></orm:Property>
            <orm:Property Name="Ime" IsPrimaryKey="false" ControlPrefix="txt"  ControlName="txtIme" BindProperty="Text" Display="true"></orm:Property>
            <orm:Property Name="Prezime"  IsPrimaryKey="false"  ControlPrefix="txt" ControlName="txtPrezime" BindProperty="Text" Display="true"></orm:Property>
            <orm:Property Name="BrojTelefona" IsPrimaryKey="false"  ControlPrefix="txt" ControlName="txtBrojTelefona" BindProperty="Text" Display="true"></orm:Property>
            <orm:Property Name="Adresa" IsPrimaryKey="false" ControlPrefix="txt"  ControlName="txtAdresa" BindProperty="Text" Display="true"></orm:Property>
          </orm:Properties>
          <orm:AllProperties />
        </orm:Object>
        ...
        </orm:Objects>
        </orm:Assembly>
        </orm:MappingRoot>
</dbs:MetaDataRoot>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:orm="http://stefan/ORM.xsd"
                xmlns:ui="http://stefan/UserInterface">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
               select="//orm:Assembly//orm:Objects" 
               mode="Object"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="orm:Objects" mode="Object">

        <xsl:for-each select="orm:Object">
            <xsl:variable name="dirname" 
              select ="'..\..\UI\FinalResultWebUIDesignClasses\'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="filename" 
               select="concat($dirname,@Name,'Edit','.aspx.cs')"/>
            <xsl:result-document method="text" href="{$filename}"> 
                <xsl:call-template name ="SaveButtonEvent"/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="SaveButtonEvent">

        protected void SaveButtonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        MiddletierManager mm = new MiddletierManager();
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/> objectClass = new <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>();
        <xsl:call-template name="FillTheObjectFromForm"/>
        mm.Save(objectClass);
        }
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="FillTheObjectFromForm">
        <xsl:for-each select="orm:Properties/*">
            objectClass.<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/> = this.<xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test ="@ControlPrefix = 'txt' and @IsPrimaryKey='false'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ControlName"/>.<xsl:value-of select="@BindProperty"/>;
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test ="@ControlPrefix = 'txt' and @IsPrimaryKey='true'">hdnID.Value;</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@ControlPrefix ='cbo'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ControlName"/>.<xsl:value-of select="@BindProperty"/>;
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@ControlPrefix ='dtp'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ControlName"/>.Value;
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@ControlPrefix ='chk'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ControlName"/>.Checked;
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

SAXON code used to parse the XSLT: [code file](https://hotfile.com/dl/230161114/187de85/Saxon_code.txt.html)

Here is the sample representing expected and actual transformation results:

Actual results:

```
protected void SaveButtonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        MiddletierManager mm = new MiddletierManager();
        Korpa objectClass = new Korpa();

            objectClass.KorpaID = this.
            objectClass.SifraKupca = this.
            objectClass.Datum = this.
        mm.Save(objectClass);
        }
```

Expected results:

```
protected void SaveButtonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        MiddletierManager mm = new MiddletierManager();
        Korpa objectClass = new Korpa();

            objectClass.KorpaID = this.hdnID.Value;
            objectClass.SifraKupca = this.SelectedValue;

            objectClass.Datum = this.dtpDatum.Value;

        mm.Save(objectClass);
        }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant samples here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi Martin, I just wanted to keep the post short...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run your stylesheet (only edited the file name assignment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
                xmlns:orm="http://stefan/ORM.xsd"
                xmlns:ui="http://stefan/UserInterface">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
               select="//orm:Assembly//orm:Objects" 
               mode="Object"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="orm:Objects" mode="Object">

        <xsl:for-each select="orm:Object">
            <xsl:variable name="dirname" 
              select ="'..\..\UI\FinalResultWebUIDesignClasses\'"/>
            <xsl:variable name="filename" 
               select="concat(@Name,'Edit','.aspx.cs')"/>
            <xsl:result-document method="text" href="{$filename}"> 
                <xsl:call-template name ="SaveButtonEvent"/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="SaveButtonEvent">

        protected void SaveButtonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        MiddletierManager mm = new MiddletierManager();
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/> objectClass = new <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>();
        <xsl:call-template name="FillTheObjectFromForm"/>
        mm.Save(objectClass);
        }
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="FillTheObjectFromForm">
        <xsl:for-each select="orm:Properties/*">
            objectClass.<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/> = this.<xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test ="@ControlPrefix = 'txt' and @IsPrimaryKey='false'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ControlName"/>.<xsl:value-of select="@BindProperty"/>;
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test ="@ControlPrefix = 'txt' and @IsPrimaryKey='true'">hdnID.Value;</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@ControlPrefix ='cbo'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ControlName"/>.<xsl:value-of select="@BindProperty"/>;
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@ControlPrefix ='dtp'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ControlName"/>.Value;
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@ControlPrefix ='chk'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ControlName"/>.Checked;
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with Saxon 9.5 HE Java against the input you have shown in your post and the result is `KupacEdit.aspx.cs` with the contents

```
protected void SaveButtonEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
MiddletierManager mm = new MiddletierManager();
Kupac objectClass = new Kupac();

    objectClass.SifraKupca = this.hdnID.Value;
    objectClass.Ime = this.txtIme.Text;

    objectClass.Prezime = this.txtPrezime.Text;

    objectClass.BrojTelefona = this.txtBrojTelefona.Text;

    objectClass.Adresa = this.txtAdresa.Text;

mm.Save(objectClass);
}
```

So I can't reproduce the problem. Are you sure the attributes you are trying to output exist in the input sample when the result is missing those values?

Comment: Well yes, the attributes do exist, otherwise I would get the same error in VS debug mode, in which I am getting same result as you. Only thing I have not tried yet is to install new version of saxon - I am using 9.4.4 HE.

Comment: I tried the .NET version of Saxon 9.4 HE from the command line and the result file is complete as well so I don't think it is an issue of the Saxon version.

Comment: You were right when you said this is not about saxon version, please tell me what do you mean when you say that attributes are missing from xml elements? Should I change the expression for reaching them or something? Thanks

Comment: As I can't reproduce the problem I still suspect the XML being processed just does not have the attributes the XSLT is trying to output. So I suspect you are somehow not processing the file you want to process. That is all that I can tell from the samples posted and the attempt trying to reproduce the problem. I can't make suggestions on the XSLT as that works fine and produces the wanted output for me. Try the samples you have with Saxon from the command line, if you still have the problem then post complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem, if not the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Of all the stupid mistakes I could make... It was just as you said, the wrong file path... Thanks for the help, now excuse me I am going to continue bashing my head against the wall.